# Взаимодействие классов в Ruby

Tags: ооп, ruby

Не понимаю, как в руби работает подобная реализация класса Interface. Допустим есть у нас 4 класса, как использовать один класс(class Interface), для взаимодествий всех остальных классов? Возможна ли такая реализация в рубине?

```
class Parent
   #тело родителя
end

class Childone < Parent
   #тело дочернего класса с какой то информацией и вычислениями
end

class Childtwo < Parent
   #тело второго дочернего класса с какой то информацией и вычислениями
end

class Childthree < Parent
   #тело третьего дочернего класса с какой то информацией и вычислениями
end

class Interface
   #реализует диалог с пользователем, с помощью условных операторов
   число = gets.to_i
   если число == 1 
      использовать class Childone
   а если число == 2
      использовать class Childtwo
   и т.д
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вопроса непонятно, что именно вы с классами хотите сделать.  Если
просто создавать новые значения, то просто используйте переменные:

```ruby
klass =
  case gets.strip
  when "1"
    ChildOne
  when "2"
    ChildTwo
  when "3"
    ChildThree
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "bad number"
  end

v = klass.new
puts(v.class.to_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Father
def initialize(a, b)
@a = a
@b = b
end

def foo
puts 'bar'
end
end

class FirstChild < Father
def foo
super
end
end

class SecondChild < Father
def foo
puts @a
super
end
end

a = gets.chomp
b = gets.chomp
c = gets.chomp

object = case c
when '1'
SecondChild.new(a, b)
when '2'
FirstChild.new(a, b)
else
raise StandardError
end

object.foo
```

Comment: В чём отличие от моего ответа?  Разве что у вас повторения кода (вызовы `::new`) больше.